# How to create a textbox with Chips functionality in ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a textbox for entering "skills" I want to give user the ability to enter his skills as "chips", I saw "chips" element in ionic2 but I don't know how can I combine it with "textbox"

An example about what I want is https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

Comment: I wonder how did you implement this functionality in Ionic. Care to share your solution if you have the answer please?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute I couldn't get same functionality, I created a text box with `+` button in front and showing list of items as chips under it